# HTTP access is forbidden error when unlocking account over HTTPS

Tags: express, openshift, web3js, quorum

I am building an **Express Application** that tries to deploy a Smart Contract in a **Quorum** Blockchain running in **Openshift**.

When I run the Application it tries to unlock an account to deploy the contract with.

At this step I get the following error:

```
# UNLOCKED FAILED.
Error: Returned error: account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden
[0]     at Object.ErrorResponse (/.../my-project/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:16)
[0]     at /.../my-project/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:140:36
[0]     at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/.../my-project/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:96:13)
[0]     at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/.../my-project/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
[0]     at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/.../my-project/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
[0]     at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/.../my-project/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
[0]     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/.../my-project/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
[0]     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
[0]     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1224:12)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

However, the endpoint of my Quorum node is **https**.

Here is the code causing the error:

```
const web3 = new Web3(HTTPS_QUORUM_ENDPOINT);

const account = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0];

await web3.eth.personal
      .unlockAccount(account, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("# UNLOCKED. OKAY.");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("# UNLOCKED FAILED.");
        console.error(error);
      });
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can it be that the openshift gateway to the Quorum pod is not secured, even though the Route is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the latest quorum release inherits upstream behaviour whereby it disallows unlock via HTTP-RPC for security reasons. There is a command line flag `--allow-insecure-unlock` which can be passed when starting geth which will re-allow this.

This is described in the upstream geth command line options here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

(Note that geth doesn't actually support HTTPS, so that `HTTPS_QUORUM_ENDPOINT` must actually be using HTTP, or I'm guessing it uses HTTPS to connect to a reverse proxy which then attaches to geth over the HTTP-RPC port.)